# Are all Xbox games compatible with Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360, backwards-compatibility

Are all Xbox games compatible with Xbox 360? For example, I want to play [Call of Cthulhu: Dark Corners of the Earth](http://www.gametrailers.com/game/204.html). Would there be any kind of problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, not all games are compatible. Wikipedia says that the game you mention is mostly playable and can be completed albeit with some difficulty: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Xbox_games_compatible_with_Xbox_360

Comment: Perhaps my single greatest disappointment with the XBox 360 is the lack of backwards compatibility for *Metal Wolf Chaos*.

Comment: But at least you can play more Haloes, amirite?

Comment: @GraceNote NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO